# Tkinter GUI unresponsive

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, freeze

I'm trying to make a GUI for solving an engineering design problem using a widely accepted method (implying the method is seamless).

The code for this method takes 0.537909984588623 seconds when run independently (not in tkinter but normal code), and its not too complex or tangled. When I tried to modify this code to fit into a GUI using tkinter, it becomes unresponsive after I enter all the inputs and select a button, even though the program keeps running in the background.

Also, when I forcefully close the GUI window, the jupyter kernel becomes dead.

Heres a brief outline of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import threading
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import math
class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.lbl1=Label(win, text='Alpha')
        self.lbl2=Label(win, text='xd')
        self.lbl3=Label(win, text='xw')
        self.lbl4=Label(win, text='xf')
        self.lbl5=Label(win, text='q')
        self.lbl6=Label(win, text='Reflux Factor')
        self.lbl7=Label(win, text='Tray Efficiency')
        self.lbl8=Label(win, text='Total Number of Stages')
        self.lbl9=Label(win, text='Feed Stage')
        
        self.t1=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t2=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t3=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t4=Entry(bd=3)
        self.t5=Entry(bd=8)
        self.t6=Entry(bd=8)
        self.t7=Entry(bd=8)
        self.t8=Entry(bd=8)
        self.t9=Entry(bd=8)
        
        self.btn1=Button(win, text='Total Number of Stages ', command=self.stagesN)
        
        self.lbl1.place(x=100, y=80)
        self.t1.place(x=300, y=80)
        self.lbl2.place(x=100, y=130)
        self.t2.place(x=300, y=130)
        self.lbl3.place(x=100, y=180)
        self.t3.place(x=300, y=180)
        self.lbl4.place(x=100, y=230)
        self.t4.place(x=300, y=230)
        self.lbl5.place(x=100, y=280)
        self.t5.place(x=300, y=280)
        self.lbl6.place(x=100, y=330)
        self.t6.place(x=300, y=330)
        self.lbl7.place(x=100, y=380)
        self.t7.place(x=300, y=380)
        self.lbl8.place(x=800, y=130)
        self.t8.place(x=790, y=170)
        self.lbl9.place(x=800, y=210)
        self.t9.place(x=790, y=260)
        self.btn1.place(x= 500, y= 75)
        
        
    def originalEq(self,xa,relative_volatility):
        ya=(relative_volatility*xa)/(1+(relative_volatility-1)*xa)
        return ya

    def equilibriumReal(self,xa,relative_volatility,nm):
        ya=(relative_volatility*xa)/(1+(relative_volatility-1)*xa)
        ya=((ya-xa)*nm)+xa 
        return ya

    def equilibriumReal2(self,ya,relative_volatility,nm):
        a=((relative_volatility*nm)-nm-relative_volatility+1)
        b=((ya*relative_volatility)-ya+nm-1-(relative_volatility*nm))
        c=ya
        xa=(-b-np.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a) 
        return xa
    
    def stepping_ESOL(self,x1,y1,relative_volatility,R,xd,nm):
        x2=self.equilibriumReal2(y1,relative_volatility,nm) 
        y2=(((R*x2)/(R+1))+(xd/(R+1))) 
        return x1,x2,y1,y2

    def stepping_SSOL(self,x1,y1,relative_volatility,\
    ESOL_q_x,ESOL_q_y,xb,nm):
        x2=self.equilibriumReal2(y1,relative_volatility,nm) 
        m=((xb-ESOL_q_y)/(xb-ESOL_q_x)) 
        c=ESOL_q_y-(m*ESOL_q_x) 
        y2=(m*x2)+c 
        return x1,x2,y1,y2

    def stagesN(self):
        relative_volatility=float(self.t1.get())
        nm=float(self.t7.get())
        xd=float(self.t2.get())
        xb=float(self.t3.get())
        xf=float(self.t4.get())
        q=float(self.t5.get())
        R_factor=float(self.t6.get())
        
        xa=np.linspace(0,1,100) 
        ya_og=self.originalEq(xa[:],relative_volatility) 
        ya_eq=self.equilibriumReal(xa[:],relative_volatility,nm) 

        x_line=xa[:] 
        y_line=xa[:]
    

        al=relative_volatility
        a=((al*q)/(q-1))-al+(al*nm)-(q/(q-1))+1-nm
        b=(q/(q-1))-1+nm+((al*xf)/(1-q))-(xf/(1-q))-(al*nm)
        c=xf/(1-q)

        if q>1:
            q_eqX=(-b+np.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
        else: 
            q_eqX=(-b-np.sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    
        q_eqy=self.equilibriumReal(q_eqX,relative_volatility,nm)
    

        theta_min=xd*(1-((xd-q_eqy)/(xd-q_eqX))) 
        R_min=(xd/theta_min)-1 
        R=R_factor*R_min 
        theta=(xd/(R+1)) 

        ESOL_q_x=((theta-(xf/(1-q)))/((q/(q-1))-((xd-theta)/xd)))
        
        ESOL_q_y=(ESOL_q_x*((xd-theta)/xd))+theta
   

        x1,x2,y1,y2=self.stepping_ESOL(xd,xd,relative_volatility,R,xd,nm)
        step_count=1 
        while x2>ESOL_q_x: 
            x1,x2,y1,y2=self.stepping_ESOL(x2,y2,relative_volatility,R,xd,nm)
            step_count+=1 
            

        feed_stage=step_count 
    
        x1,x2,y1,y2=self.stepping_SSOL(x1,y1,relative_volatility\
        ,ESOL_q_x,ESOL_q_y,xb,nm)
        step_count+=1
        while x2>xb: 
            x1,x2,y1,y2=self.stepping_SSOL(x2,y2,relative_volatility\
            ,ESOL_q_x,ESOL_q_y,xb,nm)
            
            step_count+=1 
        xb_actual=x2 
        stagesN=step_count-1
        self.t8.insert(END, str(stagesN))
        return
        
        
        
window=Tk()
mywin=MyWindow(window)
window.title('DColumn')
window.geometry("1500x1500")
window.mainloop()
```

I read on other articles that using multiple threads brings down the load on mainloop and prevents freezing. But like I said, the code isnt very complex. Is it still because of everythings running on the mainloop? Or is there something more than meets the eye? Is multithreading the only way to go past this point?

Comment: You posted everything but the logic, that is probably where the mistake is

Comment: You can't use tkinter from multiple threads unless you have a special library of some sort.

Comment: Okay, here goes the logic behind the code in Action1. I determine equations  for two different conditions using the functions defined before this and plot them. I also plot an equilibrium curve and then determine the number of steps that can fit between these curves. Again, I do this using the functions defined prior to this, and simple math conditions. Nothing complex/ confounding involved. Just simple math. And like I said, theres no error in the logic, because I tried to dry run the code before incorporating it into tkinter. The methods called "Mccabe Thiele Method" .Thanks for responding.

Comment: @TheLizzard, I didnt quite get you. Can you throw some light on what you  mean when you say "special library"? Thanks for the response

Comment: @IamARobot There is no error in the above code either and it is supposed to work perfectly fine. We can't help you unless you provide the code you wrote for the logic.

Comment: @IamARobot you can't call tkinter methods/create tkinter object while you aren't in the main tkinter thread (where you created your `tk.Tk`). If you really want to be able to access tkinter objects from a different thread, you can create your own library that uses queues to funnel all of the tkinter references to 1 thread.

Comment: @JacksonPro I've added the code now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code doesn't look as simple as you make it sound, because of using matpotlib and other modules it might be unresponsive.

If you leave a Tkinter GUi running for a long period of time it causes errors and doesn't respond,

following might help:

- splitting the code into classes and proper structuring
- prevent many while loops and def functions running at the same time
- don't call multiple functions from another function at the same time
- prevent back and forth loops

but doesn't fix the whole problem of unresponsiveness

tkinter is a really basic GUI for making small programmes/games. even if your code is not that complex it would be better to use an alternative powerful GUI